# Cannot find specific XML elements in XML Document

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xml, linq

I just ran into a head scratcher, I'm not quite sure why this does not work. I want to find all the elements with the attribute "video".

My XML document looks like this:

```
<MainMenu>
  <div id="BroughtInMenu">
    <div class="menuItem0">
      Menu Item
      <div class="subMenu0">
        <div class="menuItem1">
          Dictation
          <div class="subMenu1">
            <div class="menuItem2" video="1">Fee Earner</div>
            <div class="menuItem2" video="1">Secretary</div>
            <div class="menuItem2" video="1">View File History</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menuItem1">
          PM Advanced Agenda
          <div class="subMenu1">
            <div class="menuItem2">
              Help
              <div class="subMenu2">
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Release Notes</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menuItem2">
              System Maintenance
              <div class="subMenu2">
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Additional Field Setup</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Role Permission Maintenance</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Shared Diary Permissions</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menuItem2">
              Utilities
              <div class="subMenu2">
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Change Entity Subtype</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Field Maintenance</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Move Client and Files to Fee Earner</div>
                <div class="menuItem3" video="1">Reallocate Files</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ..
```

This is very the same as HTML. This is for a website, so at the end I want to get all the elements with the attribute "video".

If I can do this, then I will only grab the div elements with the attribute "video", and then I will be able to use that for something else, like in a search, where I actually search the xml document and return the div, etc etc... hope you see my drift here...

Because the video attribute is going to point to a location, it will be very useful for html purposes  to just jump to the video when the div is clicked.

So far I have tried this, but i am not getting the elements at all:

```
                XElement xDoc = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("automation/xml/mainMenu.xml"));
                IEnumerable<XElement> list = from el in xDoc.Elements("div") where el.Attribute("video") != null select el;
                foreach (XElement element in list)
                {
                    //Nothing found?
                }
```

I also thought about REGEX... maybe regex will be able to pull the divs i want, already in text format so that i can just push it into an html element in the website?

Any help will be greatly appreceiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Descendands` instead of `Elements`. `Elements` returns just immediate children.

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("automation/xml/mainMenu.xml"));
var list = from el in xDoc.Descendants("div")
           where el.Attribute("video") != null
           select el;
foreach (XElement element in list)
{
    //Nothing found?
}
```

Comment: Awesome to the max :)

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements where a particular attribute is present with XPath. To use the XPath extension methods, you need to include the namespace.

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

An XPath such as "//div[@video]" will include all "div" tags at any level, but filter the selected elements to *only* those with a "video" attribute, so you're not looping unnecessarily through lots of elements checking for the presence of an attribute.

```
var xDoc = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("automation/xml/mainMenu.xml"));
foreach (var divWithVideo in xDoc.XPathSelectElements ("//div[@video]")) {
    Console.WriteLine (divWithVideo);
}
```

Here you are only iterating on the elements with a "video" attribute.